# Laravel how can optimize multi queries that separated by only statuses

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-optimization, laravel-query-builder

Now I am getting `all items`, `active items`, `inactive items` and their counts using 3 queries.

This is current my function to get them.

```
public function getItems()
{
    $items = $this->model->with('category')->latest()->get();
    $count['all'] = $items->count();
    $all = view('components.item', compact('items'))->render();

    $items = $this->model->with('category')->latest()->whereStatus(1)->get();
    $count['active'] = $items->count();
    $active = view('components.item', compact('items'))->render();

    $items = $this->model->with('category')->latest()->whereStatus(0)->get();
    $count['inactive'] = $items->count();
    $active = view('components.item', compact('items'))->render();

    return response()->json([
       'all'=>$all
       'active'=>$active,
       'inactive'=>$inactive,
       'count'=>$count
    ]);

}
```

How can I optimize those quires to one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just retrieve only once

```
$items = $this->model->with('category')->latest()->get();
```

and then filter with collection where method

```
//active
$activeItems = $items->where('status', 1);
$activeCount = $activeItems->count();

//inactive
$inactiveItems = $items->where('status', 0);
$inactiveCount = $inactiveItems->count();
```